# unity3d xcode build for iOS "object is not signed at all"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

it's been some days we are encountering this problem for iOS build of our game.
problem started when we lost our development device (macbook pro-retina (Yosemite) - stolen, sadly).
Fortunately all code was saved in our mercurial repository. As we planned to launch our alpha test phase for the same day, we borrowed another macbook, updated it to "capitain" and Xcode 7.1, downloaded our certificates and provisioning profile from apple developer center and tried building a signed project. We seem to get the same error ever since "Object is not signed at all".
We revoked and renewed our certificates but the problem still persists. We clean the project every time before building.

We are somehow new to apple development and we hesitate to go with deep signing.
Our build is an iOS export of our unity3d project and the only framework we are using is AppoDeal.

We seem to have some additional information recently, saying "command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

Can it be because we are working with another person's laptop? (with apple we can't be sure). How can we have a more verbose log of error?

Any help and suggestion is appreciated.
[image]

Comment: The game is signed as distribution or debbug ?

Comment: For alpha test on chosen devices (using device UDID), so distribution (we have signed it using our AdHoc licence).

Comment: By the way, the problem was solved by itself... so we don't know how... but we have built, signed and sent our game for testing. Anyway if someone finds an answer, it would worth sharing